# Import css or scss file into Fable/F# React Component?

Tags: reactjs, f#, fable-f#

I'm using Webpack bundler and configured appropriate loaders for **.fs, .scss, .css** files.
Now how do I import a stylesheet into a Fable based React Component?

```
open Fable.React
open Fable.React.Props

// open 'MyComponent.scss' ????

type MyComponent(props) =
         inherit Component<unit, unit>(props)
```

I know there's no straight forward way to achieve this. But there's no clear documentation about the same. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

```
Fable.Core.JsInterop.importAll "MyComponent.scss"
```

Comment: I was getting this error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'JobBoardView.scss' in '/home/steve/Documents/KysoCal/src/Client/Jobs'

Changing: Fable.Core.JsInterop.importAll "JobBoardView.scss"

to: Fable.Core.JsInterop.importAll "./JobBoardView.scss"

fixed the issue and now it works perfectly.